# Apache SSL error - Unable to configure server certificate for stapling

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to configure SSL on apache2 with geotrust SSL. I have the private key file, the certificate and the bundle sertificate.

This is the virtualhost config:

http://pastebin.com/38ygh8W1

The apache gives me error: 
AH02235: Unable to configure server certificate for stapling

The https gives time out for the 443 port.

I read a lot of info for this topic but im not sure what to do anymore.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should add the relevant part of your code in your question.

Comment: Have you read this: https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1642333-apache---enable-ocsp-stapling and added the SSLCACertificateFile directive?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be bug that where the fix still hasn't made its way to the latest environments. I have the same problem. Here's my environment:

Server version: Apache/2.4.41
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

As a workaround, you can edit `ports.conf` so that the last listen directive is for a non-SSL port, i.e. `Listen 80`. Here's the whole file:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443 https
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

Listen 80
```

And the problem is gone.